# Backbone.js multiple tables data manipulation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, dom-manipulation, backbone.js-collections

I have 3 separate tables in my page and they all get filled on View Initialize and fetch their data from my backend REST Api. After fetching data i bind the reset to method called `paint` and inside that loop through the collection and construct the table.

```
paintSelected: function (collection, options) {
    collection.each(function (ch) {
        var view = new ChannelViewDetailed({model: ch});
        view.setOwner(collection);
        this.$el.find('#selected tr:eq(' + collection.indexOf(ch) + ')').after(view.render().el);
    }, this);
},
```

this constructs the whole table on my defined underscore template. all is fine at this point and i can handle remove and add data between the multiple collections on this page.

When i want to perform an `exclude all` or `include all` operation on this tables things get messed up, the view owners get lost due to loops that i have to make, duplicates show up in the list and ordering gets lost.

```
ChannelViewDetailed = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template: _.template($('#tpl-channel-row-detailed').html()),

    events: {
        'click td.del': 'deleteSelected'
    },

    setOwner: function (collection) {
        this.owner = collection;
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    deleteSelected: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.owner.remove(this.model);
        this.remove();
    }
});
```

please note that all that was mentioned above works fine when performing per item actions, but doesn't function as expected when i wan't to perform batch (include all / exclude all) operations.

this is a sample of exclude all method i've trying to accomplish.

```
excludeAllChannels: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var self = this;

        if (!$.isEmptyObject(self.selected)) {
            _.each(this.selected.models, function (item, index, items) {
                self.selected.remove(item);
            });
            $('#in-channels tr').has('td').remove();
            unsavedState = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modification of an array you are currently looping through can cause unexpected results.

https://jsfiddle.net/c0xpzq6v/

```
var a = new Backbone.Collection(data);
_.each(a.models, function(item) { a.remove(item); });
```

Can be replaced by any of the following

```
_.each(_.clone(a.models), function(item) { a.remove(item); });
a.remove(a.models);
a.reset();
```

Comment: i have no idea how you did it, but man it works like a charm !

Comment: because in some cases you override reset binding, [.clone()](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) is the preferred way.